# Из за чего эти ошибки и как их исправить mod_fcgid

Tags: php, apache, smarty

Раньше сайт на `CMS simpla` работал на `php 5.2`, после перехода на `5.6` не работала часть функционала, откатил до `5.3` и все было нормально до сегодня.   Сайт лег, через пол часа вернулся обратно.
Вот часть логов когда сайт не работал

> PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli(): [2002] Operation now in progress (trying to connect via tcp://db7.freehost.com.ua:3306) in /sata1/home/users/user/www/site.com//api/Database.php on line 46
>    PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /sata1/home/users/user/www/site.com//api/Database.php on line 90
>    PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Operation now in progress in /sata1/home/users/user/www/site.com//api/Database.php on line 46
>    PHP Warning:  Could not connect to the database:  in /sata1/home/users/user/www/site.com//api/Database.php on line 51
>    PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /sata1/home/users/user/www/site.com//api/Database.php on line 90
>    PHP Warning:  Database::results(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /sata1/home/users/user/www/site.com//api/Database.php on line 136
>    PHP Warning:   in /sata1/home/users/user/www/site.com//api/Database.php on line 136
>    PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /sata1/home/users/user/www/site.com//api/Settings.php on line 28
>   ...
>    PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /sata1/home/users/user/www/site.com//api/Pages.php on line 60
>    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Unable to load template file 'main.tpl'' in /sata1/home/users/user/www/site.com//Smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php:163
>    **Stack trace:**
>    #0 /sata1/home/users/user/www/site.com//Smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(550): Smarty_Internal_Template->isExisting(true)
>    #1 /sata1/home/users/user/www/site.com//Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php(338): Smarty_Internal_Template->getRenderedTemplate()
>    #2 /sata1/home/users/user/www/site.com//api/Design.php(67): Smarty->fetch('main.tpl')
>    #3 /sata1/home/users/user/www/site.com//view/MainView.php(32): Design->fetch('main.tpl')
>    #4 /sata1/home/users/user/www/site.com//view/IndexView.php(65): MainView->fetch()
>    #5 /sata1/home/users/user/www/site.com//index.php(75): IndexView->fetch()
>    #6 {main}
>      thrown in /sata1/home/users/user/www/site.com//Smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php on line 163

Сейчас все работает нормально, после обновления php сайт живет своей жизнью.
Из за чего это, как исправить ошибки?
На хосте 3 сайта, с одинаковой версией CMS, но при этом 1 работает стабильно, а 2 нет.

Comment: `Could not connect to the database` нет подключения к базе данных. Спрашивайте хостера, что сменилось на сервере.

Comment: сначала разберитесь пропаданием коннекта к БД, затем убедитесь что шаблон  `mail.tpl` на месте. а то мб он как то из БД вытягивается. Также удостоверьтесь, что используемая версия `smarty` поддерживает вообще php 5.6, ибо если у вас smarty 2.x то он и не заработает на 5.6, вроде как.

Comment: там есть вариант класса `SmartyBC` для обратной совместимости. но вроде на сайте симплы версии пхп и поболее указаны, так что должно работать.